# Best Practice to Unpack Longer Tuples (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, tuples, unpack

### Passing a longer tuple into a function, and want to unpack into specific variables.

**High-level:**

- I instrument some metrics (Prometheus), let's say 5-6 of them
- Metrics get put into a tuple, and passed into a function as an arg
- Unpacking in said function seems to result in some of the new variables actually being type 'tuple' rather than the Prometheus Metric Objects I'm expecting

**Given what I'm trying to do, my question are:**

- Am I properly using / unpacking the tuple?
- Is there possibly a limitation in tuple use that explicitly impacts this?
- Is there a better approach altogether in how to manage this scenario?  I went with a tuple because I like the immutability, and the ability to explicitly assign variables to the particular metric objects.  But if there's a better way, I'm entirely open to it.

**Already Tried:**

- Confirming the number of vars matches the number of metrics in the tuple

**Here's the instrumentation and placement into tuple:**

```
multicast_sequence_problem_total = Counter(
    "multicast_sequence_problem_total",
    "Total of Sequence Errors (Multicast)",
    ['source_dc', 'destination_dc', 'vlan']
),
unicast_sequence_problem_total = Counter(
    "unicast_sequence_problem_total",
    "Total of Sequence Errors (Unicast)",
    ['source_dc', 'destination_dc', 'vlan']
),
multicast_duplicate_total = Counter(
    "multicast_duplicate_total",
    "Total of Duplicate Sequences (Multicast)",
    ['source_dc', 'destination_dc', 'vlan']
),
unicast_duplicate_total = Counter(
    "unicast_duplicate_total",
    "Total of Duplicate Sequences (Unicast)",
    ['source_dc', 'destination_dc', 'vlan']
)
latency_gauge = Gauge(
    "latency_average_gauge",
    "Latency Average",
    ['protocol', 'source_dc', 'destination_dc', 'vlan']
)
metrics = (
    multicast_sequence_problem_total,
    multicast_duplicate_total,
    unicast_sequence_problem_total,
    unicast_duplicate_total,
    latency_gauge
)
```

**Skip to my other function where I actually increment / set the metric values -- here's the unpack:**

```
mcast_seq, mcast_dup, uni_seq, uni_dup, avg_latency = metrics_tuple
```

**Went in with pdb in order to debug, and found that 3 of the 5 metrics are actually type: tuple:**

```
(Pdb) type(metrics_tuple)
<class 'tuple'>
(Pdb) type(avg_latency)
<class 'prometheus_client.metrics.Gauge'>
(Pdb) type(mcast_seq)
<class 'tuple'>
(Pdb) type(mcast_dup)
<class 'tuple'>
(Pdb) type(uni_seq)
<class 'tuple'>
(Pdb) type(uni_dup)
<class 'prometheus_client.metrics.Counter'>
(Pdb)
```

So this is causing some errors when I get farther along in my code.  Python thinks I'm trying to unpack in other places (where I'm not expecting a tuple!)

Comment: Can you show us how you are trying to use one of the tuples and the error message you are getting?

Comment: We can't reproduce this without `Counter` and `Gauge`, so please make a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for having a look @wjandrea !

I was able to figure it out after digging deeper with the set trace.  

There were 2 errors: 

- 'tuple' object has no attribute 'labels' <--- This was a big clue since there was no reason for the metrics to be tuples, and they were the only ones w/ labels

- too many values to unpack <--- This was the initial one I was getting, where a list of objects should have been iterable, but was returning this error instead. 

Thanks for your time folks, but ultimately it was a syntax issues that was just not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the answer after using a dictionary rather than tuple.  My metrics objects were tuples, and the reason is that I forgot to remove some commas between the metrics where they're instrumented.

That only would have made sense if I instrumented while instantiating the dictionary or tuple all at the same time (which I didn't).

(facepalm) -- Took a while to figure out, but the pdb output saved me.  Showed me that only *some* of the metrics were tuples, not all of them.  Seeking out the difference between them led me to the answer.